# UPDATE sql table value of the currently logged in user?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, alter

I have this page with a login system, and a point system. Everytime a user completes a task, he or she will recieve +5 points. Now, how do I UPDATE the value of point in my database of the currently logged in user?

I know I can do `UPDATE table SET point=+5 WHERE id=usersid`, but I can't figure out how to get the id of the currently logged in user? The login and register system is written with PDO.

Here is my full code of config.php:

```html
<?php
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbname = "login";
     
    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
    try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); }
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Kunne ikke forbinde til databasen: " . $ex->getMessage());}
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    session_start();
?>
```

And here is my reward.php, which is not working:

```html
<?php
 require('config.php');

 $userId = htmlentities($_SESSION['user']['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

 $query = "UPDATE users SET point=point+5";
    //Yes, i do realize that i need a WHERE to avoid updating the whole     table.

 echo("$userId's point er opdateret.");
?>
```

The echo part in reward.php echoes the logged in users username just fine, but the database is just not updating. No errors either.

[Screenshot of table structure](http://i.gyazo.com/fc02a998054c63414ec9367b8df930b0.png)

Huge thanks for the answers guys, much appreciated!

Comment: You'd have to store the user id in a session, when the user logs in, and grab it from there when you need it. At least that's how I'd do it.

Comment: When logging in, you can set a $_SESSION['userId'] = ID OF USER.
And then just use this session to get the userId from any page you're using, as long as session_start(); is called.

Comment: How do you determine if the user is logged in or not ?

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` and edit your question adding the results?

Comment: @CoderofCode When the user logs in i start a session in my config.php file. I can then use `require('config.php');` to determine if they are logged in.

Comment: @Djip Thanks, i will try that. session_start is being called in my config.php already.

Comment: So get the uerid or username whatever in your session and then determine which user it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit a certain user's points only by knowing their user ID (or some other value unique to that user).

As you made clear in the comments, you save the user ID in a session. What you have to keep in mind is to include your `config.php` in every page where a user's points are updated.

```
require 'config.php';
```

The next thing you need to know is that you can get the user's ID back from the session using PHP's global session variable.

```
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id']; // Note: this could have some other name in your case
```

Now that we have the user ID we can start updating that user's points. I don't know what your method of communicating with the database is so I left that up to you.

Now we'll want to update the users points.

```
$query = "UPDATE users SET point=point+5 WHERE user_id='".$userId."' LIMIT 1";
```

That's all there is to it.

Comment: I have tried writing the query in a seperate file, reward.php, and redirecting to it. I know that this is not a secure way to do it, but it was all just for testing purposes.

No matter what, i don't get any results, and the points won't update. What am i doing wrong? I am almost 100% positive that my code is correct.

I am not getting any errors either.

Comment: If there's no errors, I suspect that there is no record in your table with the corresponding user_id.

Comment: That is not the problem @Peter, i have tried copy/pasting my PHP $query code into the phpmyadmin SQL command line, and it did just what i wanted it to.

Comment: @metadog Could you add your code (without usernames and passwords) to your question. While you're at it, your table structure would be usefull aswell.

Comment: @metadog `session_start()` should always be at the top of your script

Comment: That didn't fix it. @Peter

Answer (score 1):

I think you need

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=someDatabase', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE table  SET point = point + 5 WHERE id = :usersid');
$stmt->execute(array(
':usersid'   => $user_id
));
```